# Slow mongodb on ruby on rails

Tags: vps, ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a ruby on rails application with mysql and mongodb (mongoid framework) running.

I tested a load test with siege with the setting `-c 60 -r 10` on one page which have 2 stationsong find queries. it takes over 22 sec each. this is the query:

`QUERY database=**** collection=stationsongs selector={"$query"=>{"station_id"=>12812}, "$orderby"=>{"_id"=>-1}} flags=[] limit=10 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil`

Both stationsongs find queries are the same (and yes i know i should make it to one, but it still is huge slowness)

I only have a little over 1 million in the collection, and have index on station_id and _id. The VPS have 4 cores with 32 GB RAM.

Why is it so slow?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a mixed issue. It was performance on the VPS both also on index on mongodb. I added correct index and it fix some of the issue but had still some slow queries due to the slow CPU. So moved to a dedicated server and everything got fixed, answering under 80 ms now, instead for 22 sec.

The VPS was overloaded with clients so my CPU was 60-70% stolen power.